# How to get the html title from the page that loads in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

This is sure a popular question.. But I did not post it without reading those.. well 80% of them doesn't have a valid answer.. just the talk about same origin policy.. Well My php pages r all in the same domain..

So this is what I was getting in most of the places that had some logical answers..

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       document.title=$("#mainFrame").contents().find("head").find('title').html();
    });
```

my iframe's id is "mainFrame".. I want to get the title of the page that loads inside the iframe & set that title as the parent's title everytime.

So is there any efficient way to do that? this snippet doesn't work.. I tried.. it returns undefined!

Comment: Is the code snippet you posted in the main page or in the iframe? Also, have you tried setting a breakpoint on that line to check when it gets run? Maybe it is getting run before the iframe is loaded, that would be a very likely option.

Comment: this is on the parent page which contains the iframe! -_-

Comment: tried the snippet both at page beginning n end.. not working!

Comment: why was the question down voted?! -_- ya it is an obvious one.. still no working solutions were there.. what could I have done!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. In your parent just do:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('mainFrame'), // Or $('#mainFrame')[0],
    iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentWindow.document || iFrame.contentDocument;

document.title = iFrameDoc.title;
```

`contentDocument` is the iframe's document.

Comment: when I am using this one.. the abosulte path is being returned.. which is "http://localhost/projectName/"

Comment: to be clear it always return the root path of the project.. not the path of the page iframe loads

Comment: Are you sure your document has a title? Or that the title isn't the root path? Try the update to this post.

Comment: To add to this - browsers block this kind of access to the "contentWindow" or "contentDocument" when the origin/domain of parent and child are different

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = $( "#frame_id").contents( ).find( "title").html( );
$( document).find( "title").html( title);
```

Comment: dude I tried it before this one.. not working.. well at least not on firefox 37

Comment: plane old javascript way: `document.title = document.getElementById("main-content-iframe").contentDocument.title;`

Comment: to be clear it always return the root path of the project.. not the path of the page iframe loads